# mysqli_real_escape_string() returning empty string

Tags: php, mysql

anyone have this solution??i am having this problem from this evening after sudden blue screen error. I was using this simple code to implement session in project something worked but after that mysterious restart this thing is acting weird!!!!

This code is supposed to work!!!!

**UPDATE: Took care of some minor mistakes and its fully operational now :)**

```
    <?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        else
        {
            // Define $username and $password
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];
            // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root","company");// Selecting Database
            if (!$connection) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }
                // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
                //$username = stripslashes($username);
                //$password = stripslashes($password);

                $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$username);
                $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$password);



                // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
                $query = "select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'";  

                //$query = "select * from login where password='".$password."' AND username='".$username."'";



                $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


                if ($rows == 1) {
                    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                    header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                    }
                    else {
                        $error = "Username or Password Invalid";
                        }
                        mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
                        }
                        }
?>
```

Output image(before editing) -

[image: Output Image]

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$username);` pass connection string too

Comment: [**RT*M**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and don't mix MySQL APIs. `mysql_close($connection);`

Comment: either use `stripslashes` or `mysqli_real_escape_string` not both at the same time

Comment: and don't store plain text passwords. If you're going LIVE with this, good luck.

Comment: Pass query result to `mysqli_num_rows($result)` not your query read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: actually i used **mysql api** at 1st......I am still learning :p @Fred-ii-

Comment: Hmmmm edited that and using the 2nd one now....Sorry for my mistake...edited the code before submitting here  @Saty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_real_escape_string($username)` is missing a required parameter

The usage of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function is following:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);
```

You have to add a $connection (your connection variable). So that it becomes:
`mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username)`

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is the escape string that I use

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('escapestring')) {

function escapestring($vconnection, $value, $datatype) { 

  $value = function_exists('mysqli_real_escape_string') ? mysqli_real_escape_string($vconnection, $value) : mysqli_escape_string($vconnection, $value);

  switch ($datatype) { 
    case 'text':
      $value = ($value != '') ? "'" . $value . "'" : "'na'";
      break;      
    case 'int':
      $value = ($value != '') ? intval($value) : "'na'";
      break;  
    case 'float':
      $value = ($value != '') ? floatval($value) : "'na'";
      break;
    case 'date':
      $value = ($value != '') ? "'" . $value . "'" : "'na'";
      break; 
    }
    return $value;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can You give me some overview about what is going on when **a case is matched** ???

i mean whats the use of **?** here??

Comment: The ? and : is known as a tienerary operator. it is a shorthand if and else statement. ? being if and : being else

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not using quotes properly it will take `'$password'` and `'$username'` as it is instead of their values, change it to this-

```
$query = "select * from login where password='".$password."' AND username='".$username."'";
```

Instead of this

```
$query = "select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'";
```

plus you need to use `mysqli_close()` instead of `mysql_close()`and `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username)` as suggested by *pavlovich*.

Comment: Checked and **both worked**   yes, i had some minor mistakes there. fixed all of them and it s working fine now. :)